# How to add border between td's in which are in different tr's?

Tags: javascript, html, css

To simplify my problem I wrote the below html and css to give an overview. I want to add border between A/C and B/D. How can I do that ? If I am not clear on my question then please let me know.
Thanks.

```css
table.test {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.tdLeft {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 390px;
}
.tdRight {
  padding-left: 4px;
  width: 390px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-left: solid;
  border-width: 1px
}
```

```html
<table class="test">
  <tr>
    <td class="tdLeft">
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdRight">
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You may want to edit the question to clarify that you want the line to be continuous under the two cells, without the spacing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to remove the td tags that surround the td with data in them.  td aren't nested.  If you want to assign a class that will apply to all td in a given tr, then assign the class to the tr.

Now to add the border: we can do this with simple CSS, along with adding a class to your html:

```
<table class="test">
  <tr class="firstRow">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The following CSS gives you two distinct lines - one beneath A, one beneath B.

```
table.test {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.tdLeft {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 390px;
}

.tdRight {
  padding-left: 4px;
  width: 390px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.firstRow td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

If you want to have a single continuous line beneath the two cells (underline the entire row), you need to adjust other parts of your CSS - remove the border-spacing, and set border-collapse to collapse:

```
table.test {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.tdLeft {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 390px;
}

.tdRight {
  padding-left: 4px;
  width: 390px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.firstRow td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrea... the best explanation anyone could give me to get this started. Thanks I took your suggestions ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why are you adding <td> inside another <td>

Instead you can do

```
<table class="test">
   <tr class=row>
     <td>A</td>
     <td>B</td>  
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

css

```
tr:nth-child(1)>td{
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
}

table.test{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n197somp/)

[Updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n197somp/3/)

Comment: The border should be continuous. I ran your code and you see how there is gap between line under A and B. I want it all connected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
table-border=1px; 
Simple !

Comment: This border should be continuous.

Comment: just use table-border="whatever px you want" and try it inside the table tag which includes your td's !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will do the trick:

html

```
<table class="test">
  <tr>
      <td>
      <td class="tdLeft">A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>
      <td class="tdRight">C</td>
      <td>D</td>
          </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
table.test {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.tdLeft {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  width: 390px;
}
.tdRight {
  padding-left: 4px;
  width: 390px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-left: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n197somp/1/

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can give like this `<table class="test" border=1px>`

Comment: Don't guess, Give a verified answer! Also your syntax is invalid. The 1px should be soraunded by quotes